# Open or Select Excel and Execute a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a program that allows me to decide which Excel file I want to open and when I have selected it, I then execute the Macro "test".

Right now I do it having the file located in `C:\STATES\` but I would like to change the code and be able to put that when I click on the program button, it asks me which Excel file I want to open and once selected I run the Macro " test".

I am attaching the code that I have now, I am doing it in VB 6.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    ret = Ejecutar("C:\ESTADOS\BBDD ALEX.xlsm" "Test")

    If ret Then 
        MsgBox "Estados terminados", vbInformation
    End IF
End Sub


Función Ejecutar (Libro As String, Macro As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Error_Function

    Dim Excel As Object
    Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Excel.Visible = False
    With Excel
        .Application.workbooks.open Libro
        .Run (Macro)
    End With

    Set Excel = Nothing
    Ejecutar = True
    Exit Function

Error function:
    If Not Excel Is Nothing Then Set Excel = Nothing

    If Err Then
        Mgbox Err.Description, vbcritical
    End If
End Function
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) • Instead please describe your *actual* problem and what is wrong with your code/attempt. Which errors do you get and where, or where exactly did you get stuck. A list of requirements or *"it didn't work"* is not useful, according to [ask] a question is required that can be answered.

Comment: Note that `Función Ejecutar` is no valid VBA code and would throw an error. It must be `Function Ejecutar`